# What would be the cause of measuring AC voltage across a LM7805?

Tags: voltage-regulator, repair, ac-dc, electrolytic-capacitor, troubleshooting

This is my first time here so I apologize if I don't provide enough information.  I am trying to repair a centrifuge that is giving an error on its LCD display.  Though the service manual doesn't say what this error means, (other than its an electronics issue) based on my online research it is due to high/low Vout on LM7805.  Others who have encountered this issue with the instrument recommend to replace the electrolytic caps by the LM7805 (circled yellow in photo below).  I successfully replaced those (circled green = 50V 47uF and circled blue = 25V 220uF) but it did not resolve the issue.  I tested the Vin and Vout with a multimeter and received 3.0 VDC and 0.7 VDC, respectively. I heard somewhere that the voltage regulator could be full of 120HZ notches due to an upstream capacitor going bad so I decided to measure AC voltage for Vin and Vout I got 5 VAC and 0.9 VAC, respectively.  I still haven't replaced the 250V 560 uF power supply filter cap but I have ordered a replacement.  I was just wondering if anyone might know if there are any other potential faulty components upstream that could cause AC voltage to be detected on the LM7805 (bad bridge rectifier, LM7805 itself, etc)?    Unfortunately I could not find a schematic for this instrument.  But here is a photo of the PCB below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The input voltage of the 7805 must remain above about 7 volts for the chip to produce a regulated 5 volt output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter.  I understand that.  I know I am not providing much info (such as a schematic) but I guess I am asking for ideas/suggestions as to why I am seeing AC or ripple voltage across the regulator.  The LM7805 cannot be used for AC voltage.

Comment: If the 7805 input has a ripple that causes the voltage to drop below ~7V, the output of the regulator will also drop below 5 V whenever the input voltage goes below ~7V, causing an apparent AC voltage on the output.  Your problem originates somewhere before the 7805 - possibly replacing the 560 uF capacitor will help.

Comment: Okay thats what I was thinking as well.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: 3.0 is not enough inout voltage to get a sensible output from an LM7805. you'll need to check where the input voltage for the LM7805 is made.

Comment: @fmashockie It appears that the image there came from someone who is already trying to provide you with information about the board. Or did you place those notes there? Also, the UC2844 output voltage isn't specified. Is it a 12 V output? Or something different? I'm guessing that its output is the input source for the 7805. If so, that is a relatively complex circuit preceding the 7805 to diagnose. Hopefully, that large filter capacitor (I'm assuming it accepts the output of a bridge rectifier) replacement will be all there is to the problem. Otherwise, things get more serious I suspect.

Comment: The problem might be on input or output side of the 7805. If something is shorted or drawing too much current on the 5V output, it will also draw too much current from the supply to 7805 input. If that is not the case, then the upstream supply can be faulty or it can be OK and simply have another circuit drawing too much current. As that is a switch mode power supply it might have issues starting up on its own due to capacitors or transformer auxiliary winding.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input!  @jonk I did not place those notes there.  This is a screen grab from a forum.  The board is at my work and I didn't have it in front of me.  But Vcc of the U2488x is also the input of the LM7805 so it = 16V.  Vref = 5V and is also the output of the 7805.  I hoping the large filter cap will do the trick as well!

Comment: @fmashockie I don't think the input to the 7805 is 16 V. I think the 16 V figure is the targeted input voltage to the UC2844, which it self-regulates as well. It's output is probably lower than that. There is that string of resistors used to drop the voltage, but I think the 16 V is semi-unregulated. The schematic on the datasheet (down a ways) shows something like that, as I read it anyway.